# One Update statement with multiple cases and where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-update, case, grouping

I have a table that has the following columns

```
june_hours
july_hours
august_hours
... 
april_hours
may_hours
```

I wanted to have a trigger on my that would say 
if june_hours is null set it to zero if sept_hours is null set it to zero. However, I would like to do this in one update statement.

```
UPDATE  a
SET     july_hours = 0
From    LT_VOLUNTEER_HOURS a
    JOIN inserted b ON a.id_key = b.id_key
    where a.july_hours is null

UPDATE  a
SET     sept_hours = 0
From    LT_VOLUNTEER_HOURS a
    JOIN inserted b ON a.id_key = b.id_key
    where a.sept_hours is null
```

and so on ... 
What I would like to do if it all possible
is say

```
update table
set
    case where june_hours is null = 0
    case where sept_hours is null = 0
    case where april_hours is null = 0
```

is this feasible? 
I've been doing some reading and I can't find anything that says yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should really be storing each of the "hours" as a separate row in a table.  This would makes this update easier -- and probably a lot of other queries as well.

In any case, you can do:

```
update table
    set june_hours = coalesce(june_hours, 0),
        sept_hours = coalesce(sept_hours, 0),
        april_hours = coalesce(april_hours, 0)
    where june_hours is null or sept_hours is null or april_hours is null;
```

EDIT:

Your code looks like it is being run in a trigger.  The same idea holds:

```
update vh
    set june_hours = coalesce(june_hours, 0),
        sept_hours = coalesce(sept_hours, 0),
        april_hours = coalesce(april_hours, 0)
    from LT_VOLUNTEER_HOURS vh join
         inserted i 
         on vh.id_key = i.id_key
where lv.june_hours is null or lv.sept_hours is null or lv.april_hours is null;
```

Of course, you can extend this to all months.  The `where` clause is optional but it does make the intent of the query more obvious (and can reduce overhead).

Comment: Yes, we are using triggers - I didn't design the table structure and we have to use it as it was set up, your second set of code worked - Thank you!